# MySQL: Generate values of Table2 through entries of Table1

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a database for our storage, I want to have the first table store each individual item so that I can store specific things like a Mac-address and such. I want a second table that keeps track of the item in general, storing the total amount and in/out cost of that item. I however have no idea how to set up the second database.

Example of desired DB below

```
STORAGE
id       | product  |   in  |  out
_____________________________________
1        | ProductA |   50  |  75
2        | ProductA |   50  |  75
3        | ProductB |  100  |  150
4        | ProductB |  100  |  150
5        | ProductB |  100  |  150

TOTAL
product   | total   | total in | total out
__________________________________________
ProductA  |    2    |   100    |    150
ProductB  |    3    |   300    |    450
```

I'm not sure if what I want is even possible, any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Maybe it's also a possibility to have an 'Update' button on my management page made through PHP, Although i'm not sure how that'd work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a view for your "total" table.

```
CREATE VIEW storage_total AS
SELECT product, COUNT(*) AS total, SUM(`in`) AS total_in, SUM(`out`) AS total_out
FROM storage
GROUP BY product;
```

and you're good to go. From now on you simply do

```
SELECT * FROM storage_total;
```

to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need this second table, since you can get all information out of the first table with the according sql statements. Storing this information redundantly would leed to many problems, like when you update the first table, you need to remember to also update the second table. If you forget and the information in the two tables is not the same - how do you know, which information is the correct one and which is wrong?

If you really want this table in your database to look at it, I'd recommend to create a VIEW instead of a TABLE, that simply shows the information which is gathered from the first table.

It is definitely possible to implement this, but I would not recommend it.

To create the sql statement that extracts the information for the second table out of the first, I'd recommend to look at the `GROUP BY` statement.